# how to put string as input and run on ml engine

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I want to build a Chinese sentiment analytics on Google ML Engine.
my input is string as sentence and I also need do some string process such as replace newline, split string to chars and pad char sequence to fixed length.

this is my sample code, I want to try my idea:

```
import tensorflow as tf
input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.string, [None])
cleaned_x = tf.regex_replace(input_x, '[\s]+', '')
chars_x = tf.string_split(input_x, delimiter='', skip_empty=True)
paddings = [[0, 0], [0, 1000 - chars_x.dense_shape[0]]]
padded_x = tf.pad([chars_x.values], paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values='<UNK>')
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

print(sess.run(input_x, feed_dict={input_x:['abcd']}))
```

but I get the Exception:

```
(tensorflow) chinshunjus-MBP:Desktop chenjunru$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    padded_x = tf.pad([chars_x.values], paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values='<UNK>')
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1922, in pad
    tensor, paddings, constant_values, name=name)
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4363, in pad_v2
    constant_values=constant_values, name=name)
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 513, in _apply_op_helper
    raise err
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 510, in _apply_op_helper
    preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1040, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 235, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
    value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 433, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 341, in _AssertCompatible
    raise TypeError("List of Tensors when single Tensor expected")
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

I cannot find the cause, very thanks for your help.

or how can I implement the sentiment analytics and the input is the string array case, thank you.

[update] after removed [], also get the same exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
  padded_x = tf.pad(chars_x.values, paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values='<UNK>')
File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1922, in pad
  tensor, paddings, constant_values, name=name)
File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 4363, in pad_v2
  constant_values=constant_values, name=name)
File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 513, in _apply_op_helper
  raise err
File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 510, in _apply_op_helper
  preferred_dtype=default_dtype)
File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1040, in internal_convert_to_tensor
  ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 235, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
  return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 214, in constant
  value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 433, in make_tensor_proto
  _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/tensorflow/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 341, in _AssertCompatible
  raise TypeError("List of Tensors when single Tensor expected")
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

[update] after changed the paddings, get below exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    paddings = tf.concat([[[0, 0]], [[0, 1000 - chars_x.dense_shape[0]]]], 0)
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/mlengine27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1181, in concat
    return gen_array_ops.concat_v2(values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/mlengine27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 949, in concat_v2
    "ConcatV2", values=values, axis=axis, name=name)
  File "/Users/chenjunru/Documents/python_workspace/mlengine27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 483, in _apply_op_helper
    raise TypeError("%s that don't all match." % prefix)
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [int32, int64] that don't all match.
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be other errors in the code, but the stack trace has the answer to your question:

```
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    padded_x = tf.pad([chars_x.values], paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values='<UNK>')

TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

That is, you are passing a list of tensors to `tf.pad`, whereas it expects a single tensor (cf [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad)). Also, TF is going to similarly treat the `paddings` argument as a list of tensors instead of a 2-D matrix. To address both problems:

```
paddings = tf.concat([
    tf.constant([[0, 0]], dtype=tf.int64),
    [[0, 1000 - chars_x.dense_shape[0]]]
  ], 0)
padded_x = tf.pad(chars_x.values, paddings, 'CONSTANT', constant_values='<UNK>')
```

Note that I haven't scanned the code for further issues.

Comment: thanks for your response, I also got the same exception after I removed the [].

Comment: Are you sure it's the same exception?

Comment: yes and above sample can be test. I updated the result into question.

Comment: TF is treating `paddings` as a list of tensors instead of a 2x2 tensor. I'll update my answer with how to address

Comment: fixed by explicitly coercing the python lists to int64 (see code)